# How to count number of points above a least square fit?

Tags: python, pandas, least-squares

I want to count the points above the least squares fits.

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from astropy.io import ascii
from scipy.stats import norm
from astropy.timeseries import LombScargle
from astropy import stats

data4= pd.read_csv('Standard Dev main pop.csv')
names4 = data4.columns
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data4, columns=names4)
df3.head()
#print(c)


data5= pd.read_csv('2 Sigma Main pop.csv')
names5 = data5.columns
df5 = pd.DataFrame(data5, columns=names5)
df5.head()


data6= pd.read_csv('3 Sigma main pop.csv')
names6 = data6.columns
df6 = pd.DataFrame(data6, columns=names6)
df6.head()

a=df5['Mean Mag']
b=df5['Std']

c=df6['Mean Mag']
d=df6['Std']

e=df3['Mean Mag']
f=df3['Std']

ax=plt.scatter(e,f, label=' All sources')
#ay=plt.scatter(c,d, label='3 Sigma from Median Std')

lstsq_coefs = np.polyfit(a, b, deg=2)
lstsq_preds = lstsq_coefs[0]*a**2 + lstsq_coefs[1]*a + lstsq_coefs[2]

plt.plot(a, lstsq_preds, linestyle="dashed", color="red", label="Least squares 2 sigma")


#ay=plt.scatter(c,d, label='3 Sigma from Median Std')

lstsq_coefs1 = np.polyfit(c ,d, deg=2)
lstsq_preds1 = lstsq_coefs1[0]*c**2 + lstsq_coefs1[1]*c + lstsq_coefs1[2]

plt.plot(c, lstsq_preds1, linestyle="dashed", color="black", label="Least squares 3 sigma")
plt.legend(loc='best',fontsize= 16)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches((12,10))
plt.ylim(0,0.1)
plt.show()
```

I want to count the number of points that lie above each least-squares fit. I have tried some extremely tedious methods which is not feasible in the long run.

[image: Current plot I have]

Answer (score 0):

You can compare them using `numpy` module:

```py
import numpy as np
f = np.array(f)
lstsq_preds = np.array(lstsq_preds)
lstsq_preds1 = np.array(lstsq_preds1)
print("Number above least squares #1:", len(f[f > lstsq_preds]))
print("Number above least squares #2:", len(f[f > lstsq_preds]))
```

Note that, I just transform the arrays to numpy to make sure they are numpy. It might be unnecessary to use these transforming lines since you are dealing with pandas dataframe.